# What's the best way to include a build number for Native App Google Analytics tracking?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, google-analytics, metadata

I understand how to send the **App Version** number, but not being able to filter on the **App Build** number is becoming increasingly difficult.  Is there a best practice on where to include the Build Number?

Would it be to append it in parentheis in the 'App Version' variable or as a custom metric? Not sure what would be best.

I'm doing this for both an Android and iOS implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately. =(

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the best option is to add it to a custom dimension, since any other option would require string parsing:

- [Android Custom Dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets#set-send)
- [iOS Custom Dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets#set-send)

Comment: That's a shame.  Although not a solution definitely a solid work around. Thanks!